# When I have a timed poll function, how can I call it manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following `poll()` function:

```
var pollTimeout = 5000;
(function poll(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({ url: "/ajax/livedata.php", success: function(data){
         if (data[0] == 'success'){
            // i'm doing some irrelevant updating here
         }
         poll();
      }, dataType: "json"});
   }, pollTimeout);
})();
```

It's being executed every 5 seconds and everything works fine.

However, how can I execute this function manually? For example, I need to execute it here:

```
$("#status-update-form textarea").keyup(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == '13'){
      var status = $(this).val();
      $.get("/ajax/update-status.php", { 'status' : status },
         function(data){
            $("#status-update-form textarea").val('').blur();
            // <-- I need to execute the poll here, so that
            // the status is updated immediatelly after it's
            // submitted, not when the poll fires seconds later
         },'json'
      );
   }
});
```

Any idea how can I do this? If I try to fire poll(), it says the function doesn't exist.

Comment: Factor the common code into a separate named function that you can call in the two places you need it.  Pass arguments to that function if you need a slightly different behavior in one place vs. the other.

Comment: You could turn poll() into a regular named function and register it with setInterval() instead. That way, it can be called separately without invoking another setTimeout.

Comment: @Jack: Using `setInterval` could lead to problems if the AJAX calls take longer than expected, no? I'd probably put the `poll()` call in a `complete` handler on the `$.ajax` and stick with `setTimeout`.

Comment: @RiMMER you may put your function in window object so it will be available, where you want. Thanks

Comment: @muistooshort it's a possibility, but intervals of 5s rarely give issues I reckoned.

Comment: Does the current answer by Akhil resolve the problem properly, without creating the "longer calls problems"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your poll to a regular function

```
var pollTimeout = 5000;

function poll(timeout){
   return setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({ url: "/ajax/livedata.php", success: function(data){
         if (data[0] == 'success'){
            // i'm doing some irrelevant updating here
         }
         poll();
      }, dataType: "json"});
   }, timeout);
}


$("#status-update-form textarea").keyup(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == '13'){
      var status = $(this).val();
      $.get("/ajax/update-status.php", { 'status' : status },
         function(data){
            $("#status-update-form textarea").val('').blur();
            poll(0);
         },'json'
      );
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the timeout code from the function it actually calls, then call it manually or automatically.

```
var pollTimeoutDelay = 5000;
var pollTimeout = null;
function pollNow(){
  if (pollTimeout !== null);
    clearTimeout(pollTimeout);
    pollTimeout = null;
  }
  // do what you do, then in the callback:
  timeout = setTimeout(pollNow, pollTimeoutDelay); 
}
```

You can then call pollNow() whenever you like, it will do the thing, then re set the timeout again.

- This method uses three variables in the global scope, if this is a large application it might be worth refactoring it some more.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `setTimeout()` in a function in this case. This code below makes sure that the ajax request is killed every time you call `poll()` (once at start, every 5 seconds and every keyup event call)

```
var timeout;
var pollTimeout = 5000;
var ajaxCall;
function poll(){
      if (null != ajaxCall) {
         ajaxCall.abort();
      }
      ajaxCall = $.ajax({ url: "/ajax/livedata.php", success: function(data){
         if (data[0] == 'success'){
            // i'm doing some irrelevant updating here
         }
         poll();
      }, dataType: "json"});
}
poll();
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    poll();
}, pollTimeout);
$("#status-update-form textarea").keyup(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == '13'){
      var status = $(this).val();
      $.get("/ajax/update-status.php", { 'status' : status },
         function(data){
            $("#status-update-form textarea").val('').blur();
            poll();
         },'json'
      );
   }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: poll is not defined